# Как подключить в проект иконки Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, mvc, icon

Где нужно прописывать путь до иконок Bootstrap, чтобы они начали отображаться на HTML-странице. Подключаю так (предполагается, что слева на кнопке должна быть картинка стрелочки, указывающей влево: [image: стрелка влево]):

```
<button class="Main_Button" href="#">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
   Back
</button>
```

В CSS-файле:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('themes/base/glyphicons') format('png');
    /*src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');*/
}

.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.glyphicon-arrow-left:before {
    content: "\e091";
}
```

Все картинки лежат по адресу: `~/Content/themes/base/glyphicons`.

Answer (score 1):

Пока что работает только так.

```
<button class="My_Button">
   <img src="~/Content/glyphicons/glyphicons-211-left-arrow.png" align="bottom" /> 
   Back
</button>
```

Но это решение не очень хорошее, так как картинку нельзя перекрасить, а хотелось бы! Шрифты все подключила, но толку - ноль. Работает только вставка отдельной картинки.

Answer (score 0):

вот в этом злементе:

```
.glyphicon-arrow-left:before {
    content: "\e091";
```

Comment: спасибо что поправили

Comment: как??? Тут надо адрес к картинке прописать?

Comment: ну вот ответ ниже -- он тоже верный , но с before можно так же работать как и с обычным элементом , разница лишь в том что этот элемент присутствует но ложно как бы (!) и так же можно указать и background и так же адрес до картинки - не знаю какая у вас cms но наверно wp и если есть папка images поместите туда изображение или спрайт или что там у вас и точную ссылку на неё